# Sound playing even after closing the application in Java

Tags: java, swing, audio, jframe

So, I am making a game using Java and I wanna add background music to my application. So, I created a class `SoundManager` and wrote this code in there:

```
package Managers;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import Main.Game;

public class SoundManager {
    ClickManager cm;
    Clip c;
    public SoundManager(ClickManager cm) {
        this.cm = cm;
    }
    public void setFile(String name) {
        try {
            File file = new File(name);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            c = AudioSystem.getClip();
            c.open(ais);
        }catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    public void loop() {
        c.loop(c.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
    public void stop() {
        c.stop();
        c.close();
    }
    public void play() {
        c.setFramePosition(0);
        c.start();
    }
}
```

I am using this class for both sound effects and the background music. The sound effect seems to work fine, but when I try to implement the background music using this code:

```
cm.sm.setFile("/Game/res/sound/bg.wav");
cm.sm.play();
cm.sm.loop
//cm and sm are the name of classes
```

My background music plays as expected and loops too. But when I close my window, I still hear the background music. I think it should stop automatically when window is closed. But I have to restart my computer to stop the sound

Comment: JDK is running in the background, I don't exactly know how to fix this but it also happens with android development, you can see that even after shutting down an emulator you can see the JDK thread of that emulator running in the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should override your window's `windowClosing()` event and call `cm.sm.stop()`.

(To clarify what I meant by 'override':

```
myMainWindow.addWindowListener(
    new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            // your code here...
        }

    }
);
```

)

Comment: I have done what you have said but it still doesen't play when i click close button. I even tried doing end task using task manager

Comment: As a test, can you call `cm.sm.stop()` while your program is _still running_ - does _that_ stop the sound? If it does, but it won't stop when you close your main window, it suggests you are calling it too late, but I can't see why stopping it during `windowClosing()` doesn't work.

Comment: See: [How to Write a WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

Comment: @CODERZ: Make sure you are adding a listener to achieve the override - I have edited my original answer to show an example of what I meant. Sorry if I confused anyone.